# Block background from scrolling when open a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I've been trying to solve this problem and I tried like almost everything I found on google but I did not find a solution. How can I block the background from scrolling when the modal is opened? What I've tried works on Desktop version but when I do a localhost and test it on both iOS and Android does not work and it keeps scrolling.

I tried to add block the background with jquery by hiding the body but this is not working.Another one that I tried is adding body.modal-open{overflow:hidden;}. Any help would be welcomed, thanks.

```js
$("#popUpWindow").on("show", function () {
   $("body").addClass("noscroll");
     }).on("hidden", function () {
   $("body").removeClass("noscroll")
});
```

```css
#popUpWindow{
  background: lightblue; 
}

body.modal-open{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.noscroll { overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <h2>Simulacron 3 is the story of a virtual city (total environment simulator) for marketing research, developed by a scientist to reduce the need for opinion polls. The computer-generated city simulation is so well-programmed, that, although the inhabitants have their own consciousness, they are unaware, except for one, that they are only electronic impulses in a computer.

The simulator's lead scientist, Hannon Fuller, dies mysteriously, and a co-worker, Morton Lynch, vanishes. The protagonist, Douglas Hall, is with Lynch when he vanishes, and Hall subsequently struggles to suppress his inchoate madness. As time and events unwind, he progressively grasps that his own world is probably not "real" and might be only a computer-generated simulation.</h2>
  <h2>Simulacron 3 is the story of a virtual city (total environment simulator) for marketing research, developed by a scientist to reduce the need for opinion polls. The computer-generated city simulation is so well-programmed, that, although the inhabitants have their own consciousness, they are unaware, except for one, that they are only electronic impulses in a computer.

The simulator's lead scientist, Hannon Fuller, dies mysteriously, and a co-worker, Morton Lynch, vanishes. The protagonist, Douglas Hall, is with Lynch when he vanishes, and Hall subsequently struggles to suppress his inchoate madness. As time and events unwind, he progressively grasps that his own world is probably not "real" and might be only a computer-generated simulation.</h2>
<h2>Simulacron 3 is the story of a virtual city (total environment simulator) for marketing research, developed by a scientist to reduce the need for opinion polls. The computer-generated city simulation is so well-programmed, that, although the inhabitants have their own consciousness, they are unaware, except for one, that they are only electronic impulses in a computer.

The simulator's lead scientist, Hannon Fuller, dies mysteriously, and a co-worker, Morton Lynch, vanishes. The protagonist, Douglas Hall, is with Lynch when he vanishes, and Hall subsequently struggles to suppress his inchoate madness. As time and events unwind, he progressively grasps that his Simulacron 3 is the story of a virtual city (total environment simulator) for marketing research, developed by a scientist to reduce the need for opinion polls. The computer-generated city simulation is so well-programmed, that, although the inhabitants have their own consciousness, they are unaware, except for one, that they are only electronic impulses in a computer.

The simulator's lead scientist, Hannon Fuller, dies mysteriously, and a co-worker, Morton Lynch, vanishes. The protagonist, Douglas Hall, is with Lynch when he vanishes, and Hall subsequently struggles to suppress his inchoate madness. As time and events unwind, he progressively grasps that his own world is probably not "real" and might be only a computer-generated simulation.own world is probably not "real" and might be only a computer-generated simulation.</h2>
<h2>Simulacron 3 is the story of a virtual city (total environment simulator) for marketing research, developed by a scientist to reduce the need for opinion polls. The computer-generated city simulation is so well-programmed, that, although the inhabitants have their own consciousness, they are unaware, except for one, that they are only electronic impulses in a computer.

The simulator's lead scientist, Hannon Fuller, dies mysteriously, and a co-worker, Morton Lynch, vanishes. The protagonist, Douglas Hall, is with Lynch when he vanishes, and Hall subsequently struggles to suppress his inchoate madness. As time and events unwind, he progressively grasps that his Simulacron 3 is the story of a virtual city (total environment simulator) for marketing research, developed by a scientist to reduce the need for opinion polls. The computer-generated city simulation is so well-programmed, that, although the inhabitants have their own consciousness, they are unaware, except for one, that they are only electronic impulses in a computer.

The simulator's lead scientist, Hannon Fuller, dies mysteriously, and a co-worker, Morton Lynch, vanishes. The protagonist, Douglas Hall, is with Lynch when he vanishes, and Hall subsequently struggles to suppress his inchoate madness. As time and events unwind, he progressively grasps that his own world is probably not "real" and might be only a computer-generated simulation.own world is probably not "real" and might be only a computer-generated simulation.</h2>


  <button type='button' class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpWindow">Open Log In Window</button>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="popUpWindow">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Login Form</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- body -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log In</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: why would you add a class to your body?, just use $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); and $("body").css("overflow", "visible");

Comment: I tried. Still doesn't work... Here's a video with how it looks and how it behaves. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IihXWK7nEN8

Comment: Did you get any errors doing .css?

Comment: No. It works perfectly fine. Only when I'm testing on iOS/Android it doesn't work. On desktop version and in Inspect Element on mobile version works perfectly fine. I don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: I've done a localhost and I tested it there but the background/body is still moving when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, simply use the CSS `overflow: hidden;` property on the entire `body`, that way the whole `body` will not scroll instead of your `.noscroll` class, and then set the `overflow` property of your pop-up modal to `overflow: auto;`, that way the modal's scrolling will not be disabled. But you will also need to use `position: fixed;` because without it, scrolling is still possible on mobile devices. And after the pop-up is closed, just reset the original CSS properties for proper functionality:

```
$("#popUpWindow").on("show", function () {
   $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
   $("body").css("position", "fixed");
   $("#popUpWindow").css("overflow", "auto");
}).on("hidden", function () {
   $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
   $("body").css("position", "initial");
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried what you advised me to do but, man, I'm stupid or maybe I don't get it. So, I set the body to overflow: hidden and deleted the .noscroll class. Then I set the .modal to overflow:auto and the position fixed was already there in bootstrap.css. Also, I changed the jQuery code. Can you please give me a snippet with the code? Because I'm really stupid and I don't get it. Thanks man!

Comment: The jQuery was the code, the above paragraph just explains the jQuery below

Comment: Oh, yes, I tried it and tested it on my phone and it doesn't work :(